# Returning DB results to an Array issue

Tags: php

I am trying to push a DB results to an array.

My goal is to make an array looks like the following

```
array('test1'=>2, 'test2'=>3);
```

I have a statement as following:

```
$results=DB::call($statement, $parameter);
```

and I need to use `foreach` loop

```
foreach ($ids as $id){

  $results[]=DB::call($statement, $id);

}
```

without a `foreach` loop, my result array will be

```
array('test1'=>2, 'test2'=>3)
```

but with `foreach` loop, my array will become 2 dimension

```
//loop twice in my case

array(
     array(
      'test1'=>2,  
       test2'=>3,        
     ),
     array(
       'test3'=>4    
       'test4'=>5    
     )    
)
```

Are there anyways to concatenate my results to create 1 dimension array only? Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MERGE+ARRAY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$results = array();    
foreach ($ids as $id){

  $results=array_merge($results,DB::call($statement, $id));

}
```